# How to avoid multiple updates for default column values?

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert the record within a stored function with optional parameters and return inserted record.

Table is:

```
CREATE TABLE partner (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    status text not null default 'internal',
    active bool not NULL DEFAULT true
);
```

Note that columns status and active have default values.

Store function has both, the required and the optional params.

```
create or replace function addPartner(pname text, pstatus text = null, pactive bool = null) returns partner as $$
declare
  newrecord partner;
begin
  insert into partner
    (name)
    values(pname)
    returning * into newrecord;
  if pactive is not null then
    update partner set active = pactive where id = newrecord.id returning * into newrecord;
  end if;
  if pstatus is not null then
    update partner set status = pstatus where id = newrecord.id returning * into newrecord;
  end if;
  return newrecord;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

And calling a function would be as follows:

```
select * from addPartner('customer A', 'external', false);
select * from addPartner('customer B', 'external');
select * from addPartner('customer C');

select * from partner;
```

In case of calling the function with all params ('Customer A'), I need to execute insert a record with required param(s) and default values for optional params, and after this, for each optional param (or column with default value) execute update for optional param values. Overall, 1 insert and 2 updates.

I want to avoid these multiple updates inside a stored function and insert a new record in one SQL statement, if possible.

One insert statement with params values or default values if optional params are omitted.

Link with the previous code on rextester:
https://rextester.com/POZM9812

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL: https://rextester.com/UGA76790

```sql
create or replace function addPartner(pname text, pstatus text = null, pactive bool = null) returns partner as $$
declare
  newrecord partner;
  statement TEXT;
begin
  statement := FORMAT(
      'INSERT INTO partner (name, status, active) VALUES ($1, %s, %s) RETURNING *',
      COALESCE(QUOTE_LITERAL(pstatus), 'DEFAULT'),
      COALESCE(QUOTE_LITERAL(pactive), 'DEFAULT')
  );

  EXECUTE statement
  INTO newrecord
  USING pname;

  return newrecord;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```